# Return data after subscribing to a service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to create a custom JSON object and one key needs to be initialized with rider name. I only have an id reference to fetch the rider name from another api call. My api call is working and it does return me data i just don't know how to initialzie the key in my custom JSON object with the data returned to me by the api call. Here is my code for my custom JSON object

```
const newData = this.parcels.map((x: IParcel, i) => ({
            SrNo: i + 1,
            Id: x.id || "",
            BoxType: x.boxType || "",
            VendorOrderID: x.vendorParcelId || "",
            Zone: this.transformZones(x.zoneId)[0].name || "",
            Address: x.customerData ? x.customerData.address || "" : "",
            CreatedAt: x.createdAt || "",
            PickupDate: x.parcelStatuses[1].createdAt,
Here is the issue with Rider Name
            RiderName: this.getRider(x.loadsheetId),
            CurrentStatus: this.transform(x.currentStatusId)[0].status,
            Email: x.customerData ? x.customerData.email || "" : "",
            Phone: x.customerData ? x.customerData.customer.phone || "" : ""
        }));
```

Here is my api call to fetch rider name

```
getRider(id: string) {
        this.deliveryHttpService
        .getRiderIdFromLoadsheet(id).subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res.rider.firstName);
        })
    }
```

The rider name must be initialized with firstName. I could have made use of filter by getting all the loadSheet data first and then filtering on the frontend side but there will be too many loadSheets so its better to just make one call against an  id

Comment: Hi, @ahsan nissar, am I understand correctly, what you need to resolve `rider.firstName` for all ids in `newData` array. In this case you should create list with unique identifiers, after that you should map this ids to `this.deliveryHttpService.getRiderIdFromLoadsheet(id)` and call `forkJoin` rxjs operator to send multiple requests in parallel and handle all responses in subscribe callback.

Comment: @AlexanderFSP that seems like a possible solution but again this will involve me to make a call to create list with unique identifiers. Then how about i prefer behaviorSubject to load all Loadsheets in advance so that they can come in handy when required? Or would you still prefer creating a list with unique identifiers just before creating this custom json?

Comment: That's tricky. I think if you are sure that the user will execute this functionality - you can preload this data and store it in BehaviourSubject. But I  prefer to use the second approach to make network performance better (also you can cache this data in the subject for future purposes). I hope it helps.

Comment: okay i'll be going with behavior subject since the custom JSON is for excel download so behavior subjects will be a good option for me. Thanks your suggestion